# Calculate geometric mean in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have some email network data in Excel as a edgelist meaning I have columns Vertex1, Vertex2, and then N columns of properties of that edge like how many emails were sent from one person to another. For each row in the data, Vertex1 is the source of a message, and Vertex2 is the target, so edges are directed. Here's some sample data

```
Vertex1 Vertex2 nMessages
Bob     Cindy   12
Cindy   Bob     3
Bob     Mike    11
Cindy   Mike    1
```

I'm trying to calculate a geometric mean of the form

```
gm = sqrt[(# of edges ij)*(# of edges ji)]
```

So gm for Bob and Cindy is gm = sqrt[(messages from Bob to Cindy)*(messages from Cindy to Bob)] or sqrt(12*3) = 6. Is there a way to make that a formula in Excel?

Comment: Have you tried indexing the cells to get the names, then using one of the Lookup function to pick up the values?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I thought about using VLOOKUP, but a sender or receiver could occur more than once. How could I use INDEX and VLOOKUP together? It looks like INDEX uses just one reference, but really I have two (Bob and Cindy, not just Bob or Cindy).

Comment: Do the sender and receiver occur exactly twice (eg: [Bob,Cindy] & [Cindy,Bob]), at most twice, or more than twice?

Comment: At most twice. The pair can not exist (no messages in either direction) or exist once (messages in one direction) or exist twice (messages in both directions).

Comment: Got it.  Try this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/how-to-look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-multiple-corresponding-values-HA001226038.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can do it with a helper column. (with Excel 2007 or above, I don't need the helper column, I can post that answer if you prefer)

Assuming your example data is in A,B and C:

in D2, put `=A2&B2`, and copy that down the data

In E1, put the first name
in E2, put the second name
in E3, put the formula `=SQRT(SUMIF(D2:D5,E1&E2,C2:C5)*SUMIF(D2:D5,E2&E1,C2:C5))`

the **SumIf** checks the names, first in the order given, and adds up the number of emails, and second, in reverse order, and adds up the number.

Note that this will give **zero** if emails only go in one direction, or if no emails go between either person.

Comment: Nice answer @Sean

Comment: Thanks @Sean! I'm using Excel 2010 but don't mind using a helper column.

Comment: Much more elegant than what I was thinking which involved lookups and indexes!  Kudos!

Answer (score 0):

Without a helper column and for all xl versions

`=GEOMEAN(SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4="Bob"),--(B1:B4="Cindy"),C1:C4),SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4="Cindy"),--(B1:B4="Bob"),C1:C4))`